# Simple-DateTime picker JS close after changing month

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have a problem with the simple-datetimepicker (documentation: http://mugifly.github.io/jquery-simple-datetimepicker/). When I click on the input it opens the datepicker and I can choose a date from it. But when I switch to the next or previous month it closes the datepicker, so that I have to click it again to choose a date from that month (the month stays selected). So my problem is that datepicker closes immediately after I click on the next or previous month.

I want the datepicker to work like this: when you choose a date from datepicker start (class: datepickers), datepicker end (class: datepickere) must have a minimum date starting from datepicker start (class: datepickers).

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".datepickers, .datepickere").hover(function() {
        if ($(this).handleDtpicker('getDate') == undefined) {
            $(this).appendDtpicker({
                  "autodateOnStart": false,
                  "closeOnSelected": true,
                  "dateOnly": true, 
                  "calendarMouseScrool": false, 
                  "todayButton": false,  
                  "firstDayOfWeek": 1,
                  "futureOnly": true
            });
        }
    });

    $('.datepickers').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() > $(this).next().next().next().val()) {
            $(this).next().next().next().val("");
        }

        $(this).next().next().next().handleDtpicker('destroy');
        var minDateStart = $(this).val().replace(/-/g, "/");
        $(this).next().next().next().appendDtpicker({
            "autodateOnStart": false,
            "closeOnSelected": true, 
            "dateOnly": true, 
            "calendarMouseScrool": false, 
            "todayButton": false, 
            "firstDayOfWeek": 1,
            "minDate" : minDateStart
        });
    });
```

And HTML code:

```
<label>Datum Od: </label><input type="text" min="0" name="datumod" class="datepickers" /><br/>
<label>Datum Do: </label><input type="text" min="0" name="datumdo" class="datepickere" /><br/>
```

Here is my demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mvkuLopy/26/

But in JSfidle it opens and when I change month it does not cloes it as in my app. Is it problem somewhere else?

Comment: better if you make snippet,

Comment: @mmativ what do you mean with snippet?

Comment: Can you please check whether the `.change(function() {...}` part gets called when you change the month?

Comment: i mean, make a working demo, so we can help you, maybe try use jsfiddle or snippet here.